# Get x-path of radio button

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

need to find the regular expression for the below label

```
<div class="field radio-container valid" data-editable="true" data-type="RadioGroup" data-mandatory="true" name="gender">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="gender">
      gender
    </input>
  </label>
</div>
```

Not working when tried the following using xpath checker: name(//label/input[text() = \"" + label + "\"]/@name)

Comment: That's slightly invalid HTML (the `input` element isn't closed). Why doesn't something as simple as `//input[text()='gender']` work?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
//input[text()=\"gender\"]
```

Comment: i need to select a radio button based on label, so tried: name(//label/input[text() = \"" + label + "\"]/@name)

Comment: @ male @ female, the two radio buttons located like in the web page. Need to select one of them based on label.

Comment: <div class="validation-container icon-validation-inactive icon-align-right icon-validation-valid">
<div class="field radio-container valid" data-editable="true" data-type="RadioGroup" data-custard2id="gender" data-mandatory="true" data-regexp="^0|1|2|9$" data-id="gender" name="gender">
<div class="stack-list gutter-col-wrap-2 list-align-middle">
<div class="gutter-col-2">
<label>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="gender">
Feminin
</label>
</div>
<div class="gutter-col-2">
<label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="gender">
Masculin
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: name(//label/input[text() = "Masculin"]/@name) also doesnt work :(

Comment: What on earth is this `name(` bit that you are prefixing this all with? Get rid of it. Literally have just `//input[text()="gender"]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
click > xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox'])[position()=1]
```

to select the first radio button in your page

```
click > xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox'])[position()=2]
```

to select another one and so on

it will help you a lot to select random and any radio button